# How to make two select in Microsoft.Bot.Builder

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-teams

Create a bot for teams with different options

I'm building an app for teams in C# using Microsoft.Bot.Builder, using OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync to create a first select and OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync to create the card after an option has been selected, but I'd like to create another select before creating the card.
It seems that Microsoft has not created much documentation to be able to handle such a case. It's possible?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement, so that we can investigate it from our end.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I was trying to make a Brand Search > Product Selection > Type Selection > herocard flow but to be honest I saw it impossible to create those two selection views so I worked another solution.